# Allow users to upload files from server directory

Tags: php, file, upload

I wrote a simple pseudo-CMS using PHP and Javascript (mostly jQuery).  There is a circumstance where users can change the source of an `<img/>` tag on a given page.  I want to allow them to access (browse and select) both remote files (files on there machine) and local files (files on the web server).  In the latter case, they wouldn't be uploading as such, but simply changing the source of a given `<img/>` tag to an already existing image on the server.
      There is no real security concern I think, because the users will already have had to login to even get to this point.  The users in question are also the owners of the site, so I'm not worried about any maliciousness on their part.

Is this:

1. Possible?
   If yes, then how?
2. Potentially insecure in any way?

Thanks

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Depends on your code.

Answer (score -1):

I am answering this myself, but I won't mark it correct, because I don't like my answer.  I hope someone else finds this, and offers a better solution.

I am now using two file inputs with the user being able to choose either:

a. To upload from their desktop (as normally is the case) with the first input

or:

b. Select from a pseudo list of files from a directory on the server that has been populated with PHP `scandir()`, and then responding to their select with javascript.

It works, but I don't like it, because generating a view for a directory full of images is resource intensive, and because it requires extra coding even after that as they are not selecting a file through native browser file dialogues.

Feel free to offer a better solution.